# Can querying a static dictionary cause threading issues?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency

I have a class like (simplified version below)

```
public static class ThingyLookup
{
     private static ConcurrentDictionary<int, Thingy> cache;

     public static UpsertThingies (IEnumerable<Thingy> thingies)
     {
         foreach (var thingy in thingies)
         {
              if (thingy.Status == ThingyStatus.Deleted)
              {
                   Thingy removed;
                   cache.TryRemove(thingy.Id, out removed);
              }
              else
              {
                   cache.TryUpdate(thingy.Id, thingy);
              }
         }
     }

     public static IEnumerable<Thingy> Find (string query)
     {
         return (from thingy in cache.Values
                 where thingy != null && thingy.Name.Contains(query)
                 orderby thingy.Name
                 select thingy);
     }
}
```

Is it possible that if 2 threads are running a `Find` query, that something could happen like

- Thread 1 evaluates that where `thingy != null && thingy.Name.Contains(query)` is true
- Thread 2 updates the same `thingy` in the dictionary to be `null`
- Thread 1 tries to use `thingy.Name` in the `orderby` and thereby causes a NRE

?? If so, how to prevent while not causing deadlock?

Comment: I assume `thingies` in `Find` should be `cache` instead? It would be nice if your sample was *compilable*.

Comment: how can `thingy` in `UpsertThingies` even be `null` without causing `cache.TryUpdate` throw an NRE? Having said it´s impossible to add `nul` to your dictionary.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I fixed now. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Your specific scenario isn't an issue. The `thingy` variable in `Find` is assigned references to various objects. Nothing running in another context can *change the reference contained in that variable*, so it could never change from being non-`null` to being `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, the scenario you've described isn't possible.
To understand why let's go deep into **ConcurrentDictionary** implementation details.
When you call **cache.Values** then **ConcurrentDictionary** calls *AcquireAllLocks* that prevent us from modifying collection ( by **cache.TryRemove**, for instance) during values collection creation, creates a *List*, puts existing values into created list ( if *TValue* is a reference type then it just copies references, not cloning objects ) and then wraps created list into **ReadOnlyCollection**. So after calling *Find* method, you have an iterator based on a list of values. This list is not a part of **ConcurrentDictionary**, so any *cache.TryRemove* or *cache.TryUpdate* won't change the list (and the result of *Find* method).